# How to remove control characters in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux

I used Open3 to get result of a command like this:

```
Open3.popen3(service_command) do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
    result = stdout.read.delete(' ').split("\n")
end
```

In the string returned in `stdout.read` I found there are control characters like `\e[2K`, how can I remove those and get "clean" strings?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the full output you're receiving?

Comment: Hi Palma, the ```result``` is something like this: ```x = ["\e[mstring1", "\e[2Kstring2", "string3", "\e[2Kstrin4"]```

Comment: @pascal seems to have what you need, but in general, it is sometimes easier to retain the characters you want rather than exclude the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like these are CSI sequences (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences)

You could remove them like this:

```
REGEXP = /\e\[[^\x40-\x7E]*[\x40-\x7E]/
input = ["\e[mstring1", "\e[2Kstring2", "string3", "\e[2Kstrin4"]


def remove_csi(line)
  line.gsub(REGEXP, "")
end

output = input.map do |line|
  remove_csi(line)
end

p input
p output

# => ["\e[mstring1", "\e[2Kstring2", "string3", "\e[2Kstrin4"]
# => ["string1", "string2", "string3", "strin4"]
```

The regexp is a simplified version that matches from the start of the string  up to the "final byte" in the sequence.